# Ограничить результат запроса sql

Tags: mysql, sql

есть таблица product и таблица table_11 , в table_11 хранятся данные которые относятся к одному продукту в product , т.е. у одного продукта может быть несколько разновидностей (как например у одежды размер s/l/m) , все работает, но мне нужно сделать запрос и получить одну строку из table_11 а не 3 (в скринах все понятно становиться) , например вывести товар test1 , test2 , т.е. результат должен быть не 5 строк а 2  - sql запрос на данном этапе -

```
SELECT product.id, product.name, product.category_id, product.image, product.is_new , table_11.id FROM product, table_11 WHERE status = '1' AND category_id = '11' AND product.id = table_11.id_product ORDER BY product.id DESC
```

результат работы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

структура бд

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: можно добавить в table_11 атрибут с название sort, и в него записывать строки 1 2 3 ... на id_product 1,  а на id_product 2 уже сначала начинать 1 2 3 и делать выборку по значению, но это не рационально

Comment: Прочтите про GROUP BY

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Comment: @veti4 [Limit](http://2sql.ru/novosti/sql-limit/)

Comment: Limit не подходит так как он просто ограничивает кол-во записей , я бы сделал лимит 2 , он бы мне вывел 2 строки test2 , group by помог

Comment: Сформулируйте критерий, по которому можно однозначно установить, какую именно из трёх записей таблицы table_11, соответствующих конкретной записи из product, нужно оставить. Когда он будет - тогда можно и запрос строить.

Comment: Ну в идеале самое первое значение , мне нужно было это значение только для формирования ссылки на сайте , получается есть продукт , нажимаю на кнопку подробнее, открывается страница, в которой несколько кнопок ( разновидности данной модели (делаю запрос к table _11 и уже вывожу все значения)) потом через foreach генерирую кнопки и получаются сслыки на разные модели товара, к чему это я , впринципе пока что group by работает как нужно , ну для подстраховки можно попробовать получить самое первое значение